# Transferring a animated model from blender to unity(or unreal 5)

Tags: modeling, animation, .fbx

I have been struggling with getting this model to transfer over to a game engine with its animation. When I export the file as .fbx and upload it to either unity or unreal the surface deform cage I have connected to my mesh to control the animation looks like it gets twisted and turned inside out.

I was learning form a video online and was attempting to recreate this rig here. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l2F3OO6Jd5Y&t=1179s

Basically, its a single arm rig with a line of vertex and edges outlining the top edge of the jelly. Then connect the line to the rig to be animated with a screw modifier to encircle the rest of the mesh. After that connect the mesh to the now created cage with the mesh deform (in this case I used surface deform because mesh deform was not deforming). Then animated onto the rig.

Here are some screen shots of what I have in blender And when I transfer the files(Unreal 5 example but the same happens in Unity).

Thank you for any help in advance I hope I explained that clearly I'm kind of sick.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Export formats don't support Blender's modifiers into other software. Although it's specifically titled 'texturing', have a read through the TL;DR section of [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures) posting.